# after picking up images i want to delete photos from photoStore. Out of ideas noew

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7

```
for asset in assets{
            let phasest =  asset.originalAsset
          print(phasest?.mediaType)
          let currentPhasset =  PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(phasest?.mediaType, options: nil)
            asset.fetchFullScreenImageWithCompleteBlock({ (image, info) -> Void in
                orignalImages.append(image!)
                print (info)
                let fetchResult = currentPhasset

                    let lastAsset: PHAsset = fetchResult[1] as! PHAsset
                    print(fetchResult)
                   let arrayToDelete = NSArray(object: lastAsset)
                    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges( {
                        PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(arrayToDelete)},
                        completionHandler: {
                            success, error in
                            NSLog("Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? "Success" : error!))

                    })
```

i m using dkimagecontroller to pick images. in this code in i can delete the first photo as i pass index 1 in fetch result . if i pass any bigger number it is deleting empty data. So how can i delete selected image??i

Answer (score 0):

well . i found easy fix for that. Hope it helps someone

```
for asset in assets{
            let phasest =  asset.originalAsset
            asset.fetchFullScreenImageWithCompleteBlock({ (image, info) -> Void in
                orignalImages.append(image!)
                if (phasest != nil) {
                let arrayToDelete = NSArray(object: phasest!)
                PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges( {
                        PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(arrayToDelete)},
                        completionHandler: {
                            success, error in
                            NSLog("Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? "Success" : error!))

                    }) 

                }
```